# Server-Side redirection after a fetch request

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say, we work on a project in a web tool and after some period of time the app wants to save the project as backup before the session expire.

For the saving, we use fetch method(it could be AJAX, Axios etc) and we post a request to a controller function, in which we save the project, clear the session and want to redirect to the home page. I've tried this scenario with Laravel but when the time for redirection come, the session data is cleared but the server doesn't redirect to the home page.

Is it because of the fact that the fetch and the other types of asynchronous functions wait always for response?

Comment: the server just sends a response with a header, your browser then uses that to redirect you ... how are you handling the response you are receiving?

Comment: @lagbox If the response is "error", I display an error notification. If the response is "success" - a very short success notification.  But I thought that the server has more the power to redirect.

Comment: the server does not redirect anything, it just returns a header that says a location ... the browser is the thing that actually makes a request to that new location ... the server can't force anything, it just sends text responses, its all up to the client to interpret them and do what it needs ... it just happens to be that there are specifications for the HTTP protocol and how browsers and clients should send and receive data and what this data means

Comment: @lagbox thank you, for the explanation. Clean understood!

Comment: np, good luck with your project :)

Comment: @lagbox thank you! It's just the thing that a person has to read a lot for paradigms but on some questions, even with showed logical way of thinking, the person is not sure and sometimes need to asks dummy questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect means "What you asked for can be found here" not "Load this URL in the main browser window".

If the browser was asking for a URL with the intention of showing it in the main browser window (e.g. a link was clicked) then it would follow the redirect and show it in the main browser window.

If the browser was planning to do something else (e.g. render an `<img>`) then it would follow the redirect, get the image at the new URL, and render that in the `<img>`'s spot.

Ditto Ajax. You are making a request with Ajax, so the browser follows the redirect and gives the resource at the new URL to JavaScript to process.

If you want to make a POST request which loads a new document in the main browser window: **Submit a form** and don't use Ajax.